# flicker on tab control - WIN32

Tags: c, winapi, tabs, flicker, double-buffering

I have a WIN32 application. Its main window is `hwndMain`, one of its child is `hwndView`. There is one tab control `hwndTab` on `hwndView`.

When I resize `hwndMain`, `hwndView` is resized and so is `hwndTab`. It flicker a little, but not much.

I have tried to use `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` style ( for `hwndView` or `hwndTab`), but it just gave me blank window. I tried to use `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` and it solves flicker, but when the windows is resized to be larger, the childs are updated very slow, e.g I see black region for one second, then the region is updated.

I have successfully sloved the flicker issue for `TreeView` by using `WS_CHIPCHILDREN` style. (See remark below). But using `WS_CHIPCHILDREN` stlye for `hwndView` doesn't fix the flicker issue for tab control.

I have paid attention to `WM_ERASEBKGND` and `Not set hbrBackground` also.

I want to use double buffer for tab control, but I can't find a tutorial for this purpose. All the tutorial I found is: In `WM_PAINT`, after creating `CompatibleDC` and `CompatibleBitmap`, draw what you want in `memdc` and.....; But I don't want to do any custom drawing in `WM_PAINT` for `hwndTab`. I just want to leave the tab control do this job, but shows the final result only.

Could someone show me a small example how to double buffer a tab control (if you think this will fix the flicker issue of tab control), in the language `c` + `winapi`, since I don't have the knowledge of C#, Net,..etc.

---

Remark: For my TreeView, it is a child of a window `hwndContainer`. It is created as:

```
win->hwndContainer = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
    _T("SUMATRA_PDF_TOCBOX"), NULL,
    WS_CHILD,
    0, 0, gGlobalPrefs.sidebarDx, 0,
    win->hwndPanel, NULL,
    ghinst, NULL);
```

Using `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` fix the flicker, even if I don't use double buffer. But it is strange to put 
`WS_CLIPCHILDREN` in the first parameter position. If I put it after WS_CHILD, i.e

```
win->hwndContainer = CreateWindowEx(
    NULL,
    _T("SUMATRA_PDF_TOCBOX"), NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
    0, 0, gGlobalPrefs.sidebarDx, 0,
    win->hwndPanel, NULL,
    ghinst, NULL);
```

,then the flicker still occurs.

So I also tried to use the first way when I created `hwndView`, but it just gave blank white window.
I am really confused with these stuff.

Here is the blank window picture when I used `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` for `hwndView`.
There is no such problem when I used it for `hwndContainer`.

`hwndView` in fact has two child: a Tab Control `hwndTab` and a child which has its own double buffer and drawing. I am not sure if this cause the problem for using `WS_EX_COMPOSITED`.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. The flickering occurs because the tabs bar is drawn with a white background for the display area; then the child window is drawn on top of the display area. What I use to do was size the tabsbar so only the tab area is visible. And create a tab content that is not made child of the tabsbar but rather placed below the tabsbar. Now the tabsbar display area wont cause a flicker. The problem is this is not how tabsbar was intended to be used and it requires some measurements. But I guess tabsbar were shittily designed.

Answer (score 2):

You ***are*** using the `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` style. When you pass `WS_CLIPCHIDREN` as the first argument to the `CreateWindowEx`, it's interpreting the value of `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` as an *extended* window style. Since the value of `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` is `0x02000000L`, the same as `WS_EX_COMPOSITED`, you've just created a composited window.

And a composited window, according to the documentation, has all of its descendants painted in a bottom-to-top painting order using double-buffering.

I'm not sure what you mean when you say:

> I have tried to use WS_EX_COMPOSITED style ( for hwndView or hwndTab), but it just gave me blank window.

You'll have to post code the reproduces this problem. But your second-to-last code snippet *is* producing a composited window.

Comment: No, I didn't combine `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` with `WS_CLIPCHIDREN`. I first tried (for hwndView) `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` alone, but it gave me white blank window. Then I tried `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` in the third parameter, i.e `WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN`, no problem but doesn't fix the flicker issue.

Comment: But with you explanation, I know why it works for TreeView when I put `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` in the first parameter.